# PHP: glob in foreach multiplies with each row?

Tags: php, mysql

This is a bit confusing and hard to explain but I will try my best to explain it.

Basically, I have a directory of images (`test`) which holds all the images for my products.

The images look like this:

```
999999999Image1.jpg
999999999Image2.jpg
999999999Image3.jpg
999999999Image4.jpg
999999999Image5.jpg

555555555Image6.jpg
555555555Image7.jpg
555555555Image8.jpg
555555555Image9.jpg
555555555Image10.jpg

etc etc...
```

The numbers before Image is a field in MYSQL database called `STOCK`.

Now, I'm trying to use `glob()` to display the images for each item in mysql database like so:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    $STOCK = $row['STOCK'];

    foreach(glob('test/'.$STOCK.'*') as $image) {   

        if($image != ""){
            $pic_list2 .= '<img data-src="'.$image.'" class="smallImg" width="57" height="43" data-id="'.$STOCK.'" data-details="'.$ADVERT_DESCRIPTION_main.'" data-name="'.$MAKE2.' '.$MODEL2.' '.$DERIVATIVE2.'" data-price="'.$PRICE2.'" src="'.$image.'" alt="" />';

        }
        else{
            $pic_list2 = ''; 
        } 
    }

    /////rest of my code..../////

}
```

However, when I run my code, I get a very strange output...

The issue that I have is that with each output of MYSQL result, the images that being found by glob() is being added to the next result too! So, its like the image of the first result are being added to the next result and then the images of first result and the second results are being added to the third result and so on so forth...

I hope this makes sense and someone could point me in the right direction.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Put your foreach outside the while loop

Comment: @Mihai, I can't. the variable $STOCK is inside the while loop and that's part of the image name which I use to find the images related to each product.

Comment: Say... just a crazy idea, but wouldn't `glob('test/1*')` find also the same pictures as `glob('test/11*')`? If `$STOCK` is numeric, and there's no separator, then this seems one possible explanation.

Comment: Also, what does the query look like? Could it be possible that duplicate `$STOCK` values are returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    $STOCK = $row['STOCK'];

    $pic_list2 = ''; // you need this line also here !! only change

    foreach(glob('test/'.$STOCK.'*') as $image) {   

        if($image != ""){
            $pic_list2 .= '<img data-src="'.$image.'" class="smallImg" width="57" height="43" data-id="'.$STOCK.'" data-details="'.$ADVERT_DESCRIPTION_main.'" data-name="'.$MAKE2.' '.$MODEL2.' '.$DERIVATIVE2.'" data-price="'.$PRICE2.'" src="'.$image.'" alt="" />';

        }
        else{
            $pic_list2 = ''; 
        } 
    }

    /////rest of my code..../////

}
```

Comment: OMG, this did it.. My  $pic_list2= ''; was outside of my while loop and when i put it inside the while loop as suggested by your answer, it worked like a charm. :)

Comment: @Jackson glad it helped! happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

What about this? This creates for each mysql output a new array key.

```
<?php
$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    $STOCK = $row['STOCK'];

    foreach(glob('test/'.$STOCK.'*') as $image) {   

        if($image != ""){
            $pic_list2[$i] .= '<img data-src="'.$image.'" class="smallImg" width="57" height="43" data-id="'.$STOCK.'" data-details="'.$ADVERT_DESCRIPTION_main.'" data-name="'.$MAKE2.' '.$MODEL2.' '.$DERIVATIVE2.'" data-price="'.$PRICE2.'" src="'.$image.'" alt="" />';
        }
        else{
            $pic_list2[$i] = ''; 
        } 
    }
    $i++;
    /////rest of my code..../////
}
?>
```